# How do I extract VaR estimation from DCC-GARCH model in R?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, garch, volatility-forecasting

I have estimated a DCC-GARCH model in R and I need to extract the Value at Risk for an equally weighted portfolio from the estimated model.

```
# n = number of assets, 6
# Y = matrix of log returns for 6 assets

# Univariate GARCH model specification
specs = ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                   mean.model=list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE),
                   distribution.model = "norm") #gaussian distribution

# Replicating the specification for each asset
m_specs = multispec( replicate(n, specs) )

# Engle's DCC specification for conditional correlations
DCC_specs = dccspec(uspec = m_specs, dccOrder = c(1,1), distribution = "mvnorm")

# Fitting
DCC_fit = dccfit(DCC_specs, data = Y)
```

My question arise since I can plot the VaR for this model just stating the following:

```
plot(DCC_fit, which=5)
```

Resulting in the following plot:

[image]

QUESTION: since the plot selection clearly computes the VaR for an EW portfolio with 1% limits, is there a way to extract this computation without hardcoding it again?

Answer (score 0):

I was asking myself the same question and I just found a method that works.
You can simply extract it using the basic `quantile` function included with R.
Here with your model it would give something like this:

```r
alpha <- 0.99 # (your df)
VaR_extract <- as.numeric(quantile(DCC_fit, probs = alpha))
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to me to be an answer to the question.